# How to write native newline character to a file descriptor in Python?

Tags: python

The `os.write` function can be used to writes bytes into a *file descriptor* (not file object). If I execute *`os.write(fd, '\n')`*, only the LF character will be written into the file, even on Windows. I would like to have CRLF in the file on Windows and only LF in Linux.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm using Python 2.6, but I'm also wondering if Python 3 has a different solution.

Comment: `os.write` needs the FD as its first argument -- pls fix this question! And no, Python 3 is not essentially different (except it wants bytestrings, not text -- which is always Unicode in Python 3 -- in os.whatever calls).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use this

```
import os
os.write(fd, os.linesep)
```

Comment: You can also do `file = open("filename", "<read/write flag>"); file.write(os.linesep)` if you don't want to use os.write.

Answer (score 8):

How about `os.write(<file descriptor>, os.linesep)`? (`import os` is unnecessary because you seem to have already imported it, otherwise you'd be getting errors using `os.write` to begin with.)