# How do you define __str__ in python when including newline characters?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, newline

I'm trying to define **str**() for a maze object and have it print out something that looks like this:

```
#######
#J..P.#
#.###.#
#..@#.#
#@#.@.#
#######
```

When I build the string to return, however, it ends up getting printed as:

```
'#######\n#J..P.#\n#.###.#\n#..@#.#\n#@#.@.#\n#######\n'
```

All I'm doing is going through the list of lists (each row is a list, and the whole maze is a list of these row lists) and concatenating a "\n" at the end of each row. Is there something else I'm supposed to do to the resulting string before returning it so that the string representation of the maze when print() or str() is called on it will return that first desired representation?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: It already returns the right thing... you just need to `print` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you printing with the print statement, or just by letting Python print the value? Eg.:

```
>>> a = "This is a\nmultiline string"
>>> a
'This is a\nmultiline string'
>>> print a
This is a
multiline string
```

That's just normal Pythonic behaviour.

Comment: Well, I was trying to use doctest to make sure my methods are working as intended. Does this mean, for __str__, that doing doctests for this method won't really work (since you have to return a string as opposed to printing the string you build)?

Comment: doctest is very visual :). You can doctest `str` against what you'd expect to be shown as the result of `str`; if you want the doctest to "look nicer", you probably want to use `print` in the doctest. In that case, you might feel like you're testing `print` rather than `str`. There are other unittest frameworks.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using raw strings?  (i.e. strings wrapped in `r"""  """`  instead of `" "` or `' '`).

Also, you might consider using `os.linesep` instead of hard-coding `\n` for OS-independence.  More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223289/how-to-write-native-newline-character-to-a-file-descriptor-in-python).